# Applying function to a DataFrame using its columns as parameters

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I need to use a function to calculate a new column for a table using existing data from its 4 columns.

Suppose I have a function that calculates orders, impressions, or clicks - anytging from different sources. Something like this:

```
def claculate_new_columns(complete_orders_a, total_a, completed_orders_b, total_b):
    total = 0.0

    #just some random calculations bellow - not important

    source_a = complete_dorders_a + 1
    test_a = total_a  + 1
    source_b = completed_orders_b + 1
    test_b = total_b + 1

    for i in something(smth):
        total += source_a*test_a*source_b*test_b
    return total
```

**How do I use it with data from DataFrame columns?**

I want to run over rows in columns and insert the results in a new column.
Something like this (it doesn't work, obviously):

```
old_df['new_column'] = old_df.apply(claculate_new_columns(column1,column2,column3,column4))
```

Would be glad for a correct way to apply such functions to a DataFrame and use these DataFrame columns as function's arguments. What is the correct syntax?

Solutions from StackOverflow don't work for me probably because I searched for wrong answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda function:

```
old_df['new_column'] = old_df.apply(lambda row: claculate_new_columns(row['column1'], row['column2'], row['column3'], row['column4']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To do calculations between columns and create a new column inside a function use `apply` with `axis = 1`

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':[1,2,3,4,5], 
                   'column_2':[10,20,30,40,50]})

def func(df):
    #     All Calculations here
    df['new_column'] = df['column_1'] + df['column_2']
    return df

df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

#### results

```
    column_1    column_2    new_column
 0      1         10            11
 1      2         20            22
 2      3         30            33
 3      4         40            44
 4      5         50            55
```